# How do I prevent my bootstrap collapsible boxes from scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have 5 DIVs that use Twitter bootstrap to show or hide the information inside of them. When my page renders, two of the boxes are defaulted to open. When the height of the boxes open are taller than the screen, the page is forced to scroll to the bottom.

I want to have the page remain scrolled to the top, while forcing the overflow to the bottom, but have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: You could use the `show` and `shown` events to fix the overflow before and after. Kind of containing the effect. [collapse doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). If you show us exactly with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: I would post a jsfiddle, but the application is large and scattered, and proprietary.
I added an on(shown) scrollTop(0) so that the page would return to the top when the expansion is finished, but there are two problems with this. The page still

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/kzkmT/1/) as a playground. If you can reproduce the bug (the scrolling) then it might be easier to solve it. You may even solve it yourself while reproducing the bug in a minimalistic environment.

Answer (score -2):

It's solved with this CSS rule:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden ; 
}
```

No extra JavaScript needed, because the bootstrap modal automatically adds the 'modal-open' class to the body.